# How to extract object data from object swift?

Tags: swift

```
ATBloodOxygenData{bloodOxygens={bloodOxygen=96, heartRate=0, type=0, utc=1665405007, }, dataSize=1, dataOffset=0, remainCount=1, utcOffset=0, }
```

The above data type is [String:Any]

[image: BloodOxygens]
I can successfully get bloodOxygens data but its type is Any.

```
 let bloodOxygens =  obj?["bloodOxygens"]
```

I have convert that value to string for details

```
  let keystr=String(describing:bloodOxygens)
  print(keystr)
"Optional({\n    bloodOxygen = 98;\n    heartRate = 0;\n    type = 0;\n    utc = 1665408583;\n})"**
```

let splitedvalues = keystr.components(separatedBy: "\n")

im spliting the string to get the value but I need a proper way to get this data

```
       let bloodOxygens =  strObj?["bloodOxygens"]
        print(type(of: bloodOxygens)). ##output: Optional<Any>
```

I want to get bloodOxygen=96 from this object. I have tried multiple ways but I failed.Please help me get this data.

Comment: How do you get that object? Is that from a library or API?

Comment: @its from library

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `obj?["bloodOxygens"]` contains a JSON string. To parse it, you can use [JSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization) as shown in the following code:

```swift
if let jsonData = (bloodOxygens as? String)?.data(using: .utf8) {
    let jsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]
    print("bloodOxygen =", jsonObject?["bloodOxygen"] ?? "nil")
}
```

**EDIT:**

So the string is not valid JSON, so you'll need to parse it manually:

```swift
var result: [String: String] = [:]
for line in bloodOxygens?.split(separator: "\n") ?? [] {
    let terms = line
        .dropLast()
        .split(separator: "=")
        .map { $0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)}
    if terms.count >= 2 {
        result[terms[0]] = terms[1]
    }
}

print(result["bloodOxygen"] ?? "nil")
```

Comment: bloodOxygen = nil and also JsonObject is also nil

Comment: Ah, it's not valid JSON. I added code for manually parsing the string.

Comment: yes manual parsing is the workaround